# Triste y alegre a la vez

Tags: selección-de-palabras

¿Tenemos en español alguna palabra que exprese un estado de tristeza y alegría simultáneas? Por ejemplo: un padre en la boda de su hija siente tristeza porque su hija se va, pero también alegría por su nuevo estado. O una estudiante que acaba sus estudios siente a la vez alegría por haberlo logrado y tristeza por dejar las aulas y compañeros.

Alguien me proponía la palabra *saudade* que, aunque de origen portugués, está incorporada a nuestra lengua; pero no me acaba de convencer. ¿Alguien tiene otra propuesta?

Comment: Manu Chao utiliza "malegría" y a mí me encanta. Qué pena que aún no esté aceptada por la RAE : )

Comment: Sé que tu pedido es para una palabra concreta pero quizás lo que estés tratando de decir pueda ser comunicado con más palabras. "Alegría triste" o algo por el estilo. A veces tener una única palabra que describe algo es muy beneficioso, otras veces te encierra en la definición y lo que estás buscando es complicado de definir (incluso a nivel de empatía).

Comment: Creo que la expresión que más se aproxima a lo que describes es: *sensación agridulce*.

Comment: Buscando información respecto la _saudade_ encontré una web la mar de interesante: [20 palabras geniales que no tienen traduccion](http://matadornetwork.com/es/20-palabras-genial-que-no-tienen-traduccion/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En mi opinión, como bien han mencionado ya antes(Envite), `"tener un sentimiento agridulce"` me parece la frase mas acertada.

Sin embargo, me gustaría añadir que, si bien dicha frase se puede utilizar para acciones en tiempo presente, existe una palabra que define muy bien ese doble sentimiento en tiempo pasado: `melancolía`.

[Aquí](http://lamenteesmaravillosa.com/melancolia-la-felicidad-de-estar-triste/) puedes encontrar una explicación más amplia para definir la melancolía. Del enlace anterior, cito textualmente:

> Dice Víctor Hugo que “la melancolía es la felicidad de estar triste”.
>   Lo cierto es que cuando nos sentimos melancólicos nuestro estado de
>   ánimo suele asociarse a la tristeza, aunque lo que estamos  recordando
>   sean buenos momentos del pasado. La melancolía sin memoria no es
>   posible.

Comment: Tienes razón, el sentimiento en todas esas situaciones que describo es de melancolía.

Answer (score 7):

Yo diría "tener un sentimiento agridulce".

Comment: http://elmeme.me/Cynar/los-7-momentos-mas-agridulces-que-vas-a-vivir-en-tu-vida_46102

Answer (score 0):

A mi la que más se me acerca es "***nostalgia***". Según el diccionario de la RAE es

> Nostalgia: Pena de verse ausente de la patria o de los deudos o amigos.

Como dices tú, una estudiante que acaba sus estudios siente a la vez alegría por haberlo logrado y tristeza por dejar las aulas y compañeros. ¿En ese caso sentiría nostalgia?.

Aunque buscando en foros encuentro [esto](https://espanol.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070129141409AAbZvLP)

> En idioma español quien mas se acerca es el gallego cuando dice "*morriña*"

Pero puedo estar equivocado, corregidme si lo estoy.

Un saludo.

Comment: En los dos ejemplos que pongo en mi pregunta, ciertamente, la pena la produce la nostalgia; pero le falta la parte de la alegría. De ahí la propuesta de la *saudade*, que se parece un poco más a lo que pregunto, aunque sólo en su significado original portugués.

Comment: Por otro lado, considerar que *morriña* es una palabra en español, pero *saudade* no, como se dicen en la cita de Yahoo Answers, me parece poco acertado. Ambas son préstamos (del gallego y el portugués, respectivamente) y, si nos ponemos estrictos, ambas aparecen en el DRAE.

Comment: De todos modos, espero que mis comentarios no parezcan bruscos, que no es mi intención. Gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón y quizás he pecado de tomar prestada la palabra "*morriña*" del gallego (a lo mejor por hacer caso a la persona que contestó en Yahoo Answers). Espero que alguien pueda ayudarte algo más que yo. Siento no haber podido serte de ayuda. Un saludo.