# Palabra o expresión para definir a quien memoriza las cosas sin llegar a entenderlas

Tags: selección-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término, solicitud-de-modismo

<sub>La etiqueta [*single-word-requests*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests) de English Language & Usage depara grandes respuestas. Aquí solo recuerdo la pregunta de Gorpik [*Triste y alegre a la vez*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/13622/1674), así que vayamos a por otra basándonos en [*Derogatory word, describing person (a pupil) who memorizes instead of learning?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/313712/37429).</sub>

Todos conocemos al empollón, ese que estudia mucho pero que normalmente también acaba siendo bueno.
Sin embargo, también existe la variante de persona que *empolla* mucho pero no es capaz de entender lo que está estudiando. Tras estudiar todos los posibles problemas de matemáticas, resulta que el ejercicio es algo diferente y no es capaz de solucionarlo, por lo que suspende. En ese momento comentas con los compañeros:

> Fulanito es un XXX, mira que le dedica horas al estudio pero no lo entiende y acaba suspendiendo.

¿Tenemos en castellano alguna palabra o expresión para referirnos a XXX, es decir alguna persona que memoriza las cosas sin llegar a entenderlas?

Comment: En esta pregunta voy a aprender mucho. Nunca había oído la palabra _empollón_ ni la expresión "acaba suspendiendo" y tampoco conozco la respuesta a XXX.

Comment: Como complemento a empollón, es también bastante habitual la palabra _chapón_, al menos en mi zona. La idea es la misma, dedicar una cantidad ingente de horas al estudio, y al menos tal como la entiendo yo implica utilizar la memoria para absorber conceptos y sentencias sin preocuparse en exceso por sus implicaciones. No sé que opinará más gente sobre la acepción de esta palabra, ya que estaría enfocada hacia tu pregunta

Comment: Veo que la palabra __chapón__ no viene recogida en el diccionario de la RAE. Sin embargo, el verbo del que se deriva, __chapar__, si que aparece [aquí](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8ZfInkF).

Comment: @DGaleano _empollón_ lo usamos para quien _empolla_. La imagen es muy gráfica: cuando uno estudia está muy quieto y reconcentrado, como las gallinas cuando están incubando los huevos : )

Comment: @Jalo caramba, _chapón_ no la había oído nunca. ¿En qué zona la usáis?

Comment: La respuesta de @CarlosAlejo me parece bastante acertada. En el Perú usamos "paporreta" de esta manera: "aprendió de paporreta", o alguna vez escuché a mi madre decir: "aunque lo tengas que aprender de paporreta", ja, ja, ja. La frase de tu pregunta quedaría así: "**Fulano solo aprende de paporreta.** Le dedica horas al estudio pero no lo entiende y acaba suspendiendo".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Interesante y complicada pregunta. Estoy buscando en el diccionario (tanto el directo como [el inverso](http://dirae.es/)) y de momento encuentro lo siguiente:

- [Hablar como un papagayo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RlJ0ZVE). Decir algunas cosas buenas, sin inteligencia ni conocimiento.
- [Psitacismo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UXcQHKg). Método de enseñanza basado exclusivamente en el ejercicio de la memoria.
- [Portapapeles](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Tkp8q0J). Me resultaría divertido usar esta palabra, ya que un portapapeles sólo es un almacén temporal de datos en memoria, que no entiende lo que se almacena.

Sin embargo, creo que Perú tiene la solución a tu problema, ya que esta palabra encaja perfectamente con lo que estás buscando:

> **[Paporreta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RoFvwSH)**.
>
> 1. f. despect. Perú. Repetición mecánica de lo que se ha aprendido de memoria sin entenderlo o entendiéndolo a medias.

También tienes **[paporretear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RoGleiN)** y **[paporretero](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RoHuz41)**. Todas ellas vienen de [papo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ro44vjM%7CRo4inQ1%7CRo4izPP) (persona sin entendimiento).

Comment: En Colombia usamos otro animal. "Hablar como cotorra" en lugar de papagayo usándolo para referirnos a alguien que habla mucho y sin parar. En el contexto de la pregunta decimos "repetir como un loro".

Comment: Respecto a papagayo, en España he oído mucho «estudiar/aprender de lorito».

Comment: Iba a decir algo parecido a lo que comenta @guillem: en España podríamos decir de esa persona que es un *lorito* o un *papagayo*.

Answer (score 3):

Me parece que la expresión *autómata* es apropiada:

> Fulanito es un autómata, ya que le dedica horas a memorizar sus estudios pero no los comprende...

*Autómata* se refiere a una persona automatizada, automática, como un androide o un robot.

Answer (score 3):

En El Salvador, **guayabearse** algo es aprendérselo de memoria, no necesariamente sin entender lo que se aprende.

> Tuve que guayabearme muchas cosas cuando era estudiante. Y todavía...
>
> Muchas de las cosas que me guayabeé, todavía me sirven: las tablas de
>   multiplicar, las conjugaciones, la historia, la geografía...

Usamos **cranear** cuando de verdad estamos pensando algo: reflexionando, inventando o descubriendo una solución. En una exposición en la Universidad un compañero dijo: "Déjeme cranearlo". Todos nos pusimos a reír.

En la escuela de mi hermana se caracterizaban por aprenderse las cosas por pura memoria: cuando exponían algo, lo recitaban palabra por palabra, mecánicamente, sin preocuparse en transmitir la idea.

Así que contestando tu pregunta:

> Fulanito es pura guayaba, es pura paporreta, parece autómata, parece robot...

o mejor,

> Fulanito parece lora...

Comment: ¡Qué interesante! Curioso que en Ecuador [_guayabar_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JmqnrUT) quiera decir _mentir_ y que en Colombia [_guayabo_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Jn5GrB5|Jn6mfl6) sea la resaca.

Answer (score 3):

En España dirías "un loro":

> Fulanito es como un loro, memoriza sus estudios pero sin entenderlo.

Ya que los loros solo oyen y repiten sin saber lo que dicen.

Answer (score 1):

Depende del país, en México se les llama "Pericos".