# Alternativas para "sabiondo"

Tags: traducción, adjetivos, solicitud-de-término

En la serie de [Peppa Pig](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peppa_Pig) hay un personaje ([Edmond Elephant](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Personajes_de_Peppa_Pig)) que, cada vez que puede, corrige a los demás si ve que se han equivocado.

Ejemplo 1:

> -¿Qué frutas os gustan?
>   -A mí las peras.
>   -A mí las manzanas.
>   -A mí los plátanos.
>   -A mí las zanahorias.
>   -**E.E.:** Pero la zanahoria no es una fruta.
>   -¿Ah, no?
>   -**E.E.:** No, es una hortaliza.

Ejemplo 2:

> -[Refiriéndose a la forma de un tobogán.] Es un gran brontosaurio.
>   -**E.E.:** Perdone que le corrija, pero el verdadero nombre de este dinosaurio es "apatosaurio".

Debido a esta característica, al personaje le tildan de *un poquito sabiondo*, tanto por parte del narrador como por parte de otros personajes. El caso es que me extrañó porque pensaba que "sabiondo" era una palabra despectiva. La busqué en la RAE y encuentro esto:

> [**sabiondo, da**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WtU4l19)
>
> 1. adj. coloq. Que presume de sabio sin serlo. U. t. c. s.

Y ahí ya me extrañó, porque las cosas que dice el elefante sí que son ciertas. Así que consulté la versión original, y el término que usan en inglés es *clever clogs*:

> [**clever clogs**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clever%20clogs)
>
> A person who is clever in a way that is annoying.

Es decir, la definición en inglés no cuestiona el que el calificado como tal sea o no listo, sólo que muestra sus conocimientos de forma molesta, lo cual encaja mucho mejor con el personaje de la serie.

Por tanto, veo una discrepancia entre las dos palabras usadas en ambas versiones. La cuestión es, ¿hay alguna alternativa mejor que "sabiondo" y que refleje mejor el significado del término inglés? He encontrado *sabidillo*:

> [**sabidillo, lla**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Wt1pLsS)
>
> 1. adj. despect. Que presume de entendido y docto sin serlo o sin venir a cuento. U. t. c. s.

pero no estoy seguro de que refleje completamente el término en inglés.

Por cierto: con esta definición, "sabiondo" se postula como candidato a responder [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17334/12637).

Comment: ¡Gran pregunta! Para empezar, pensaba que solo _sabihondo_ (con "h") era válido. Veo que el tema se debatió en WordReference un par de veces ([1](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/clever-clogs.674516/), [2](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/clever-dick-clever-clogs.1251729/)) y hay sugerencias del tipo _resabiado_ (que no me parece correcta), _sabelotodo_, _agrandado_ (no la conocía pero me gusta), _fanfarrón_ (algo lejana pero que podría encajar) y, especialmente, _listillo_. Si hubiera algún nombre a partir del verbo _vanagloriar_, creo que encajaría perfectamente.

Comment: @fedorqui pues precisamente en el segundo enlace de WordReference hay una alternativa que me parece perfecta: [repipi](http://dle.rae.es/?id=W26V8jH). Un repipi es un niño [pedante](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SIBoR7f) (que hace inoportuno y vano alarde de erudición).

Comment: Pues lo mismo _pedante_ a secas es la que mejor encaja. La parte de _afectado_ no sé si la requieres para la palabra que buscas. ¿O es muy rabioso el tal Edmond? (no he visto nunca esta serie, aunque seguro que me llegará el momento :D)

Comment: @fedorqui [_afectado_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0wA5H0A|0wAWT95) tiene muchas acepciones que encajan (por ejemplo, "que pone mucho cuidado en las palabras"). Y como Edmond es un niño pequeño (va a la guardería), "repipi" le sienta muy bien.

Comment: @fedorqui [por cierto](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=sabiondo): "Lejos de ser una falta de ortografía, la forma _sabiondo_ es la originaria, ya que esta voz parece proceder de la forma reconstruida del latín vulgar _sapibundus_ (adjetivo derivado de _sapere_ ‘saber’); enseguida, y por influjo de _hondo_ (‘profundo’), surgió la variante _sabihondo_, que está desplazando en el uso culto actual a la forma originaria."

Comment: Me encantan estas etimologías. Me recuerda el caso de [_elite / élite_](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=sabiondo).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tras comentarlo debajo de la pregunta, hemos visto que en [una discusión de WordReference](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/clever-dick-clever-clogs.1251729/) ofrecen distintas alternativas:

- [*resabiado*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=W70tHiJ): *Dicho de una persona: Que, por su experiencia vital, ha perdido su ingenuidad volviéndose agresiva o desconfiada*. No acaba de encajar.
- [*sabelotodo*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Wsustft). *1. m. y f. coloq. Persona que presume de sabia sin serlo. U. t. c. adj*. Tampoco encaja, pues buscamos el caso de alguien que sí sabe.
- [*agrandado*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=18BUysH). *1. adj. coloq. Col. Que se cree superior a los demás. U. t. c. s*. Tampoco encaja, pues obvia la parte del conocimiento.
- [*fanfarrón*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Hab06xp). *1. adj. Que se precia y hace alarde de lo que no es, y en particular de valiente. U. t. c. s*. Tampoco vale, pues en este caso sí que se sabe (igual que en *sabelotodo*).
- [*listillo*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NQThQl7), ya comentada por Josías en [su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17842/1674). *4. adj. coloq. Que presume de saber o estar enterado de todo. U. t. c. s. U. m. en dim* (usado más en diminutivo). Encaja bastante con lo que se busca.

Una que tú destacaste es **repipi**:

> [**repipi**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=W26V8jH)
>   1. adj. coloq. Dicho especialmente de un niño: Afectado y pedante. U. t. c. s.

Que por edad y circunstancias parece ser la que encaja mejor en el contexto de los dibujos animados para niños.

Answer (score 9):

[*sabelotodo*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Wsustft) creo que le encaja muy bien, y además aparece en el DRAE.
A tener en cuenta que puede obtener tono despectivo en función del tono en el que se emplee (igual que sabiondo)

También hay quien emplea [*resabido*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=resabido).

Coloquialmente, en España se emplea mucho "listillo", aunque tiene connotación despectiva, y también se emplea, para hablar de aquellas personas que sacan provecho de las demás al ser más "espabiladas" . Creo que es un ejemplo de palabra con otro significado, que por uso popular está cambiando su acepción.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero ¿podrías elaborar un poco más? La palabra _listillo_ no viene en el DRAE, luego ¿cuál es el significado de _listillo_? ¿Y en qué te basas para decir que es la más usada?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo de todos modos, _listillo_ aparece en la definición de [listo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NQThQl7) y parece bastante adecuada en su acepción _4. adj. coloq. Que presume de saber o estar enterado de todo_.