# ¿Cómo se llama la persona que, desde su ignorancia, habla de todo como si lo supiera?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Sé que existe una palabra para eso, pero no logro recordarla. La definición de la misma viene a ser una persona que no sabe nada pero habla como si supiera de todo. Por ejemplo, se está hablando de un tema en concreto del que esa persona no sabe nada, y esta habla sin saber nada, pero queriendo dar la impresión de que domina la materia.

Comment: [Aquí tienes](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17841/12637) un par de opciones.

Comment: Es mucho más simple en inglés se puede decir solo jackass - y es bien para todas las ocasiones!

Answer (score 14):

La palabra que buscas es *[sabelotodo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Wsustft)*.

> **sabelotodo**
>   **1.** m. y f. coloq. Persona que presume de sabia sin serlo. U. t. c. adj.

Otra [definición](http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/sabelotodo) quizá más amplia, del Espasa-Calpe:

> **sabelotodo**
>   **1.** com. *col.* Que presume de saberlo todo o saber más de lo que sabe:
>   *ese profesor tiene un sabelotodo que le boicotea todas las clases.*

Hay unos cuantos sinónimos pero creo que esta palabra es la más usada y entendible en todas partes.

Answer (score 9):

O [**sabiondo**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=WtU4l19) (también **sabihondo**):

> 1. adj. coloq. Que presume de sabio sin serlo. U. t. c. s.

Como ves, es prácticamente la misma definición de **sabelotodo** que recoge @pablodf76 en su respuesta.

Answer (score 8):

El adjetivo "**listo**" suele significar "inteligente, sagaz, etc.", sin embargo, una de sus acepciones es un coloquialismo que le da un matiz sarcástico, como indica el DRAE, y que se ve mejor en la versión con diminutivo (*listillo*) que en el término original.

> [Listo, a](https://dle.rae.es/?id=NQThQl7)
>
> 4. adj. coloq. Que presume de saber o estar enterado de todo. U. t. c. s.
>
> (usado más en diminutivo) Siempre hay un *listillo* que sabe más que nadie.

De manera similar, tenemos "**enterado**" y "enteradillo", en su tercera acepción.

> [enterado, da](https://dle.rae.es/?id=FhAM9h6)
>
> 3. adj. coloq. Que presume de saber mucho de algo. U. t. c. s.

Answer (score 5):

A todas las apuntadas, cabría añadir desde España la de *[cuñao](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/cu%C3%B1ao)*, de *cuñado*, normalmente en masculino, como aquel que lo sabe todo sobre todo, que descubre cuan equivocados están todos, que conoce todas las ofertas, que lo encuentra todo como nadie, cuyo análisis es vital para comprender la actualidad... Es una broma sobre el *cuñado* que viene los domingos a salvar la barbacoa, y que se ha convertido en un sinónimo más a *listo*", en la acepción indicada por @Diego, *enterado, sabihondo* o *sábelotodo*.

Comment: Por cierto, el mismo @Diego se apuntó con una pregunta sobre el [cuñadismo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19090/6915).

Answer (score 1):

Aunque las principales ya las han comentado, me gustaría añadir una más que se usa solamente en Andalucía:

> *maestro liendres*, que de nada sabe y de todo entiende.

Comment: No sé si esa la he oído alguna vez en España. Deberias explicar un poco mas donde se usa. Así puesta parece casi mas un comentario que respuesta. Visita [tour], [help] y [answer] para aprender un poco mas sobre el tipo de preguntas que intentamos promover aqui.

Comment: Creo que es una expresión que se usa solo en Andalucía.

Comment: I've heard only "Maestro Liendre, mucho sabe y poco entiende.".

Answer (score 1):

Es el ***[Efecto Dunning-Kruger](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efecto_Dunning-Kruger)***, en el cual un individuo sobre estima su conocimiento pero no se da cuenta de su propia ignorancia.

Answer (score 0):

- **Marisabidilla**

Forma coloquial y despectiva en España que se refiere a alguien, normalmente una mujer, que presume de que lo sabe todo o es muy lista sin serlo o en un momento inadecuado.

- **Sabidillo, Sabidilla**

Forma coloquial y despectiva que se refiere a una persona que presume de docto o entendido, sin serlo, o lo hace cuando no es oportuno.