# ¿Qué sentimiento o emoción se forma de los celos y la nostalgia?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

¿Tenemos en español un sentimiento o emoción que exprese celos y nostalgia al mismo tiempo?  O sea, ¿qué emocion sale de esa mezcla? Y si no existe ¿cuál sería su nombre apropiado?
El recuerdo no cuenta, obviamente.

Celos + Nostalgia = ¿?

Comment: Relacionado: [Triste y alegre a la vez](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/13622/1674) Sé que es un sentimiento distinto, pero el tipo de pregunta me recuerda.

Answer (score 3):

Diría que, cuando una persona está celosa por otra que no es (ya) su pareja, *el sentimiento de celos lleva también implícito en cierta manera el de nostalgia*, pues dicha persona celosa echa también en falta la cercanía con el objeto de su deseo. Que esta cercanía fuese real en el pasado, o solo producto de su imaginación, es irrelevante de cara al sentimiento de nostalgia que la realidad de su carencia produce en la persona.

No obstante y si tuviese que escoger una palabra diferente, escogería **resentimiento**:

> [**resentimiento**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=W8yXH2G)
>   1. m. Acción y efecto de **resentirse**.
>
> > [**resentirse**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=W8z0GIl)
> >     2. prnl. Tener sentimiento, pesar o enojo por algo.

Aunque su significado no sea específicamente "sentimiento de nostalgia y celos", creo que cuadra bastante bien con lo que describes:

- [Nostalgia](https://dle.rae.es/?id=QdfICDo): pena, tristeza, pesar por esa felicidad perdida al acabar la relación.
- [Celos](https://dle.rae.es/?id=8A737TG): rabia, enfado, enojo tanto por que otra persona disfrute ahora de esa felicidad, como hacia dicha persona en sí.

Además, **semánticamente, *re-sentimiento* implica *volver a sentir***, lo cual redunda de manera algo poética en ese sentimiento de nostalgia que decíamos antes.

Yo he experimentado esa mezcla de sentimientos que dices y, definitivamente, si tuviese que describirlo con una sola palabra, diría que estaba [resentido](https://dle.rae.es/?id=W8xmkRi).

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que buscamos una palabra que exprese por un lado:

> **[nostalgia](https://dle.rae.es/?id=QdfICDo)**
>
> Del lat. mod. *nostalgia*, y este del gr. *νόστος nóstos* 'regreso' y *-αλγία -algía* '-algia'.
>
> 1. f. Pena de verse ausente de la patria o de los deudos o amigos.

Y por otro:

> **[celo<sup>1</sup>](https://dle.rae.es/?id=8A737TG)**
>
> Del lat. *zēlus* 'ardor, celo', y este del gr. *ζῆλος zêlos*, der. de *ζεῖν zeîn* 'hervir'.
>
> 3. m. Envidia del bien ajeno, o recelo de que el propio o pretendido llegue a ser alcanzado por otra persona. U. m. en pl.

Si mezclamos estas dos emociones imagino que el resultado es una emoción que implica "pena por la ausencia de algo" y a la vez "celos de la gente que aún puede disfrutar de ese algo", que podríamos llamar **nostalgia insana** o **nostalgia envenenada**. Ambos conceptos pueden dar a entender que la nostalgia está provocando un sentimiento negativo de celos o envidia más allá de la "pena", que come a la persona por dentro. Se construye por similitud con la expresión *envidia sana* o *envidia insana* (o *envidia cochina* que decimos por aquí), que se usan para denotar si una envidia provoca un sentimiento positivo o negativo. Un ejemplo de esta última expresión:

> *Con un vestido mestizo de colores, la Princesa Nicté-Ha las veía con gran gusto, con envidia sana, como si ella quisiera regresar a sus mundos infantiles del distante Yucatán.*
>
> Arturo Azuela, "La casa de las mil vírgenes", 1983 (México).

Podrías usar la expresión *nostalgia insana* y dejar claro por el contexto que la parte *insana* viene provocada por los celos, aunque no lo digas directamente.

Si buscas una única palabra, hay en el diccionario varios términos que implican "nostalgia", como *[saudade](https://dle.rae.es/?id=XM6WldQ)* que es más bien una nostalgia solitaria, *[cabanga](https://dle.rae.es/?id=6OaWLUk)* usada en Costa Rica, *[añoranza](https://dle.rae.es/?id=31ojvlf)*, *[morriña](https://dle.rae.es/?id=PrSUwFk)* que es la nostalgia por la tierra, pero todas estas voces no implican de por sí el sentimiento negativo de los celos.