# ¿Qué preposiciones usar para describir a las personas implicadas en un caso de celos?

Tags: preposiciones

Respondiendo a la pregunta [¿Qué sentimiento o emoción se forma de los celos y la nostalgia?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/29149) he encontrado cierta dificultad en describir sin ambigüedad una situación de celos.

Cuando alguien siente celos amorosos, suele haber tres personas implicadas:

- La persona que siente los celos: Alex.
- La persona que Alex ama o desea: Jess.
- La persona que interactúa con Jess: Robin.

Alex tiene, tenía o quiere tener una relación con Jess.
Jess y Robin se caen bien, hablan, interactúan... lo normal entre personas sanas.
Alex siente miedo de que Robin "le quite" a Jess, de que Jess sienta más afecto por Robin; y siente rabia hacia Robin por osar siquiera hablar con Jess, y quizá hacia Jess por "dejarse engatusar" por Robin.
Alex siente celos.

Pero Alex...

- ¿Siente celos de Robin por Jess?
- ¿Siente celos hacia Robin por Jess?
- ¿Siente celos hacia Jess por Robin?
- ¿Siente celos de Jess por Robin?
- ¿Siente celos de Jess y Robin? ¿Quién es quién, en este caso?

Preguntado de otra manera: **al decir que Alex siente celos ante la relación de Jess y Robin ¿como podría expresar *mediante preposiciones*, sin ambigüedades, que Jess es el objeto de deseo y que Robin es el objeto de rechazo?**

Comment: Tal vez los celos no se sientan ni hacia Jess ni hacia Robin, sino hacia la relación que existe entre ambos. Es ese caso se diría que Alex siente celos de la relación entre Jess y Robin. Eso implicaría que la opción válida sería que siente celos "de Jess y Robin". A fin de cuentas la definición dice que "celo" es el "recelo de que el propio o pretendido llegue a ser alcanzado por otra persona". Es decir, sientes celo por el hecho de que la persona sea alcanzada por otra, no de las personas en sí.

Answer (score 1):

Interesante.

Creo que si consultamos la definición de la DRAE al respecto, en su entrada 7, podemos ver que los celos hacen referencia no a una relación directa entre deseante y deseado, sino a una turbación del deseante a causa de una sospecha o recelo:

> [**celo<sup>2</sup>**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=8A737TG%7C8A7sRXS)
>
> 7. m. pl. Sospecha, inquietud y recelo de que la persona amada haya mudado o mude su cariño, poniéndolo en otra.

Así que para evitar la ambigüedad, debería quedar clara la causa de esos celos, es decir, quién los suscita. Si consultamos ejemplos en la red, vemos que se tiene celos de algo o alguien porque ese algo o alguien es la causa de la desazón. Por lo tanto, en este ejemplo, yo votaría por:

**Alex siente celos de Robin por Jess**

Porque Robin y su aparición es la causa de que Alex sienta celos, y el contexto de esos celos es el deseo de Alex por Jess, esa es la razón de los celos, pero los causa Robin.

Sin embargo, si Jess fuera la causa directa, es decir, si Jess entrara directamente en un juego de seducción, podría muy bien funcionar:

**Alex siente celos de Jess por Robin**

En este caso la fuente directa de celos sería Jess, y la situación sería Robin.

Comment: gracias @walen, ¡tienes razón! Lo que trataba de demostrar era que en una frase con "sentir celos de", al no ser "celos" una relación directa con algo o alguien sino al referirse a una situación, la ambigüedad era poco menos que inevitable, pero que las preposiciones dejaban claros los roles... si conocemos un poco más el contexto.